# What items can followers use in Diablo 3?

Tags: diablo-iii

I was reading about the [followers](http://diablo.wikia.com/wiki/Followers) on D3 and saw this:

> Each follower will be able to be equipped with two weapon slots, two
>   ring slots, and also one of their own unique class-specific item.

Then I start wondering which class is each follower, and saw this:

> **Templar**
>
> The Templar is not a Paladin, he is a new type of righteous warrior in
>   the Diablo universe with differing ethics and ideals.
>
> **Scoundrel**
>
> Lyndon is primarily a ranger, comparable to the Diablo II Rogue. He
>   has some other tricks as well, like blinding power.
>
> **Enchantress**
>
> She is neither a Sorceress or Wizard, but comes from a society called
>   the Hand of the Prophet.

- So, how this "unique class-specific item" works?
- The Enchantress can't use a Mage wand? Neither the Templar can use a barbarian helmet? Or the Scoundrel a bow for Hunter ?

Comment: Since the game is still in beta, it's difficult to answer the question.  Also, there's a possibility the answer (or question) will change/be irrelevant once the actual game launches.

Comment: @Toast I know that, but if/when it changes, we can always update the answer. It's difficult, not impossible. But I don't believe that it could become irrelevant (they show lot's of information about it)

Comment: See this meta discussion for why we don't allow questions that can't be answered by the current beta.  http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/4111/how-should-we-handle-non-beta-pre-release-questions

Comment: @bwarner I have read this article a while ago. But, this is a question with an answer. And as I said to +Toast, **IF** the answer change, we can change it very easily. I am not asking here what is the best follower, or something like that, that CAN'T be answered with links and nothing like that. I am asking here a simple question, with a simple answer.

Comment: @Michel Since the question can be answered from information on the official web site, that qualifies it to stay.  Though that points out a slight weakness in the policy, namely that one needs to know whether the information is on the official site in order to decide whether to close vote.

Comment: @bwarner Hmmm... I don't think this is a weakness in the policy. I looked in the site and didn't realize what Oak show me in his answer. Following this logic, independently if the question was about Mass Effect, League of Legends, Skyrim or what so ever that is on activity right now, or some pre-release game (diablo 3 for example) the answer and the question would be the same. So this is not a failure in the policy, this is an legitim question for the G.SE and i REALLY don't understand WHY someone would downvote it (like they did). or WHY someone would want to close this question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Each follower has a specific list of equipment he or she is capable of equipping. You can see this list by going to the [items page on the official site](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/item/) and clicking the follower's icon at the top; here are quick links:

- [Templar's items](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/item/#filter=templar)
- [Scoundrel's items](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/item/#filter=scoundrel)
- [Enchantress' items](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/item/#filter=enchantress)

Regarding the special follower items, those are equipped in their own special slot and do not replace any other item. That slot is not immediately available, it is unlocked later in the game.

Comment: So Templar Relics are the "Templar only", equip item. There is not a sword (for example) Templar only. And the wands is said in the link "Wizard" only, so this is impossible for a Enchantress use it. Is that right ?

Comment: @MichelAyres correct.